# How can I transform geometry data to bounds?

Tags: openlayers-2, geometry, coordinate-system

My SRID is 3137 and I want to transform geometry data(e.q : "0101000000904160258CC91841C8073D6723545141") to bounds. I need to bounds coordinates for use in maxExtend() function. Help me please!

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
var yourgeom = ["0101000000904160258CC91841C8073D6723545141"];
transformedgeometry = OpenLayers.Geometry.toString(yourgeom);
```

source: http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry-js.html